# Why doesn't the WindowPriceOnDrop() function serve as a store of price in my code?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4

I've been trading with grid orders for some time now, but just realized there is a `WindowPriceOnDropped()` function that I'd like to incorporate.

My standard order placement is written like this. Here is sample code for 5 orders spaced 5 pips apart, all micro lots, with 50 pip stops and 100 pip take profits. The first order appears close to market, just 1 pip down, and the rest follow:

```
int start()
  {
   int    ticket;
   double point;

//----

   point=MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_POINT);

//----

    ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.01,Ask-100*point,0,Ask-600*point,Ask+900*point,"[5] 1k, 1 pip down");
    ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.01,Ask-150*point,0,Ask-650*point,Ask+850*point,"[5] 1k, 1 pip down");
    ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.01,Ask-200*point,0,Ask-700*point,Ask+800*point,"[5] 1k, 1 pip down");
    ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.01,Ask-250*point,0,Ask-750*point,Ask+750*point,"[5] 1k, 1 pip down");
    ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.01,Ask-300*point,0,Ask-800*point,Ask+700*point,"[5] 1k, 1 pip down");

//----

   return(0);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm testing `WindowPriceOnDropped()`, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.mqh>
#include <WinUser32.mqh>

int start()
  {
   int    ticket;
   double point;
   double Price = WindowPriceOnDropped();

//----

   point=MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_POINT);

//----

    ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYLIMIT,0.01,Price*point,0,Price-500*point,Price+1000*point, "[5] 1k test");

//----

   return(0);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, the order doesn't appear at all. Am I missing something? The only thing I've changed is "Price", which ought to store the point value on drop due to the `WindowPriceOnDropped()` function, as opposed to Ask minus point value. Why can't I simply substitute the variable for "Ask" if the logic remains the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WindowPriceOnDropped()` returns a normalized value of the price, you can normalize again with `NormalizeDouble(double, _Digits)`. So instead of `Price*point` use just `Price` or its normalized value.